# Unable to push json to data in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

When I am using the below code with mounted function then it's perfectly pushing the data to "infox"

```html
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            infox: null,
            dino: d_var
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios
            .get(this.dino)
            .then(response => (this.infox = response.data))
    }
}
</script>
```

But when I am trying to convert the code to use method function as shown below then I am unable to get any data. Is it something I am doing wrong ?

```html
<template>

    <button v-on:click="loadmore" class="fluid ui button">Load More</button>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            infox: null,
            dino: d_var
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadmore: function(){
            axios.get(this.dino)
                .then(response => this.infox = response.data)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks right, what happens? Have you tried console.log in the .then part too check if you're getting response?

Comment: `(response => {this.infox = response.data})` maybe you forget the curly brackets.

Comment: @bcjohn I have tried that but still no data. Funny thing is if I use mounted then JSON would get render.

Comment: It looks right and should work in methods too. Where are you calling the "loadmore" method?

Comment: Is there anything in the **response**? So if you **console.log**ged it, what would it show?

Answer (score -1):

infox is set to null you should set it to array.

infox: []

Comment: Not necessary since he is just changing the value of the variable and not actually using `.push()`